# Comment Notification Email Send to Editor User role

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments

In wordpress Authors receive comment notifications for, and can moderate comments on, only posts for which they’re the “author”.
Editors receive comment notifications only for posts for which they’re the “author”, but can moderate any comments.

I want to receive comment notifications for All Author and Editor user they have ability to moderate comment.How to do this? Could you please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer!

I Created New user with Editor user Role.To send your notifications to a particular to New created Editor User I added Editor User Id "5" following code.

```
function se_comment_moderation_recipients( $emails, $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', '5' );

    // Return only the post author if the author can modify.
    if ( user_can( $user->ID, 'edit_published_posts' ) && ! empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
        $emails = array( $user->user_email );
    }

    return $emails;
}
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
```

[Reference](http://www.sourcexpress.com/customize-wordpress-comment-notification-emails/)

And this works!